# помогите , не могу запустить проект https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

Tags: spring-mvc, maven

Люди помогите , не могу запустить проект https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

java version 1.8.0_121
apache-maven-3.5.0
apache-tomcat-8.5.13

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.codeleak \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 \
    -DgroupId=my.groupid \
    -DartifactId=my-artifactId \
    -Dversion=version \
    -DarchetypeRepository=http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype
```

с опцией -X

```
[INFO] Using property: groupId = my.groupid
[INFO] Using property: artifactId = my-artifactId
[INFO] Using property: version = version
[INFO] Using property: package = my.groupid
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: my.groupid
artifactId: my-artifactId
version: version
package: my.groupid
 Y: : [DEBUG] Archetype generation configuration confirmed
[DEBUG] Found archetype pl.codeleak:spring-mvc-quickstart:1.0.0 in cache: D:\maven_repository\pl\codeleak\spring-mvc-quickstart\1.0.0\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar
[DEBUG] Found archetype pl.codeleak:spring-mvc-quickstart:1.0.0 in cache: D:\maven_repository\pl\codeleak\spring-mvc-quickstart\1.0.0\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar
[DEBUG] checking fileset archetype status on D:\maven_repository\pl\codeleak\spring-mvc-quickstart\1.0.0\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml inside D:\maven_repository\pl\codeleak\spring-mvc-quickstart\1.0.0\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/.gitignore
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/Account.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/AccountController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/AccountRepository.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/AccountService.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/Application.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/ApplicationConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/JpaConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/MongoConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/SecurityConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/WebAppInitializer.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/WebMvcConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/error/CustomErrorController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/error/ExceptionHandler.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/home/AboutController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/home/HomeController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signin/SigninController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signup/EmailExists.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signup/SignupController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signup/SignupForm.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/support/web/Ajax.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/support/web/Message.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/support/web/MessageHelper.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/application.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/logback.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/persistence-pgsql.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/persistence.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/css/core.css
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/images/favicon.ico
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/js/jquery.min.js
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/error/general.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/fragments/components.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/fragments/layout.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/about.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeNotSignedIn.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeSignedIn.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/signin/signin.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/signup/signup.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/account/AccountServiceTest.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/account/UserAuthenticationIntegrationTest.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/EmbeddedDataSourceConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/NoCsrfSecurityConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/WebAppConfigurationAware.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/WebSecurityConfigurationAware.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/signup/SignupControllerTest.java
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Entry found
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml inside D:\maven_repository\pl\codeleak\spring-mvc-quickstart\1.0.0\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/.gitignore
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/Account.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/AccountController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/AccountRepository.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/account/AccountService.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/Application.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/ApplicationConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/JpaConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/MongoConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/SecurityConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/WebAppInitializer.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/config/WebMvcConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/error/CustomErrorController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/error/ExceptionHandler.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/home/AboutController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/home/HomeController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signin/SigninController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signup/EmailExists.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signup/SignupController.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/signup/SignupForm.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/support/web/Ajax.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/support/web/Message.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/support/web/MessageHelper.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/application.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/logback.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/persistence-pgsql.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/resources/persistence.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/css/core.css
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/images/favicon.ico
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/resources/js/jquery.min.js
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/error/general.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/fragments/components.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/fragments/layout.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/about.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeNotSignedIn.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeSignedIn.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/signin/signin.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/signup/signup.html
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/account/AccountServiceTest.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/account/UserAuthenticationIntegrationTest.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/EmbeddedDataSourceConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/NoCsrfSecurityConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/WebAppConfigurationAware.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/config/WebSecurityConfigurationAware.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/signup/SignupControllerTest.java
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Entry found
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: spring-mvc-quickstart:1.0.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: my.groupid
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-artifactId
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: version
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: my.groupid
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: my/groupid
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: my.groupid
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: version
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: my.groupid
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-artifactId
[DEBUG] getFilesetArchetypeResources( "D:\maven_repository\pl\codeleak\spring-mvc-quickstart\1.0.0\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar" )
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/).gitignore
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)pom.xml
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/account/Account.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/account/AccountController.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/account/AccountRepository.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/account/AccountService.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/Application.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/config/ApplicationConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/config/JpaConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/config/MongoConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/config/SecurityConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/config/WebAppInitializer.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/config/WebMvcConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/error/CustomErrorController.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/error/ExceptionHandler.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/home/AboutController.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/home/HomeController.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/signin/SigninController.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/signup/EmailExists.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/signup/SignupController.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/signup/SignupForm.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/support/web/Ajax.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/support/web/Message.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/java/support/web/MessageHelper.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/resources/application.properties
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/resources/logback.xml
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/resources/persistence-pgsql.properties
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/resources/persistence.properties
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/css/core.css
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/images/favicon.ico
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/resources/js/jquery.min.js
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/error/general.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/fragments/components.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/fragments/layout.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/about.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeNotSignedIn.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeSignedIn.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/signin/signin.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/signup/signup.html
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/account/AccountServiceTest.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/account/UserAuthenticationIntegrationTest.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/config/EmbeddedDataSourceConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/config/NoCsrfSecurityConfig.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/config/WebAppConfigurationAware.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/config/WebSecurityConfigurationAware.java
[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)src/test/java/signup/SignupControllerTest.java
[DEBUG]   - ignored resource META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Processing complete archetype spring-mvc-quickstart
[DEBUG] Processing module my-artifactId
[DEBUG] Processing module rootArtifactId my-artifactId
[DEBUG] Processing module pom D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\my-artifactId\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing module moduleOffset 
[DEBUG] Processing module outputDirectoryFile D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\my-artifactId
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project moduleId my-artifactId
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project pom D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\my-artifactId\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project moduleOffset 
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project outputDirectoryFile D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\my-artifactId
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project basedirPom D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing pom D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\my-artifactId\pom.xml with parent D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing template archetype-resources/pom.xml
[DEBUG] Merging into D:\spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype-master-1\my-artifactId\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Adding module my-artifactId
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping Spring MVC Maven Archetype: Quickstart
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.174 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-09T16:34:47+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project spring-mvc-quickstart: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project spring-mvc-quickstart: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.codeleak</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-quickstart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>
    <name>Spring MVC Maven Archetype: Quickstart</name>
    <description>Archetype for creating Spring MVC 4 web application</description>
    <url>https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
                <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что вы запускаете генерацию проекта в **пустой** директории. В директории не должно быть других файлов и поддиректорий.

Используйте вот эту команду

```
mvn -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.codeleak \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 \
    -DgroupId=my.groupid \
    -DartifactId=my-artifactId \
    -Dversion=version \
    -DarchetypeRepository=http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype
```

Comment: я потерялся. собралось без ошибок. а сам проект:( сподключенным artifactom?

Comment: Цель, скачать и развернуть спринг мвц на мавен в идее

Comment: ваш вопрос о том, что у вас не запускается определенная команда. теперь она запускается? вы получили ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Денис не забудьте отметить ответ как принятый. Это поможет остальным пользователям.